# BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1066] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed

Tags: android, surface

There is a RecyclerView in my page and filled with TextureViews:

[Activity page capture in my demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmWse.png)
I use eglCreateWindowSurface() to create EGLSurface for every TextureViews(SurfaceTexture), and use eglDestroySurface() to destroy them when the
Activity is not visible (Stopped).

When i launch several Activities like this, i get an exception as below:

```
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1066] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1066] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1066] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1066] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
....
 E Surface : dequeueBuffer: error duping fence: 24
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E Surface : dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E Surface : dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
 E Parcel  : dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
 E Surface : dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
 E Surface : dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -2147483646
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1084] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1085] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1086] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1087] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1088] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1089] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1090] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-9639-1091] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
 E OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -2147483648
```

Does anyone have suggestions for solving this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: `07-01 05:59:04.177  6144  6165 E GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-6144-238] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000`